# "incomplete universal character name" with stringWithUTF8String

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, utf-8

when i try to convert form utf-8 string to NSString like so:

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\U0627\U0644\U0641\U0631\U0646"];
NSLog(@"%@", s);
```

i get the compile error:

```
incomplete universal character name
```

note that it sometime just works fine:

```
NSString *UAE = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\U0627\U0644\U0641\U0631\U0646"];
    NSLog(@"%@", UAE);
```

and the output:

```
الامارات
```

so why is that happening? please help.

Comment: Gee, thats a bug in Xcode. Non ASCII is still hard to get for some nations ;-)

Answer (score 37):

\U and \u are not the same thing. The \U escape expects 8 (hex) digits instead of 4.

This should work:

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\u0627\u0644\u0641\u0631\u0646"];
```

Comment: Apple actually makes this error when recording events for UI tests. (As of Xcode 7.3 at least)

Answer (score 0):

incomplete universal character name means that you are missing part of one of the utf8 character that you are trying to write.

UTF8 spans from 1 byte symbols to 4 byte symbols, probably one of yours is longer that you wrote and you are missing 1 byte or such..

Comment: thanks alot Jack,
however, im trying to parse the UTF-8 string from a webservice that i have no control over. 
Is space in the utf-8 string has any thing to do with issue. i mean how can I represent a space char in my case here?
thanks again

Comment: If the string is coming from a webservice, how are you getting a compile-time error?

Comment: actually i manually copied the utf-8 string from the dict returned and test it using the method -stringWithUTF8String, this is when i get compile-time error